# Duplex WCF doesn't work

Tags: c#, wcf

I created WCF service and client for it. Firstly, the client calls the `Register()` method which adds client's callback channel to `clientChannels`.

When client calls `SendMessage()`, server sends received data to other registered clients using `ShowMessage()` method of client callback. `InstanceContextMode` of service is `Single`.

Service host is a console application. It works normally, but client is blocked after `Register()` calling and doesn't output anything. After a while it throws `EndPointNotFoundException`:

> There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFDuplexServiceTest/Service1/ that could accept the message.

How to fix it?

Config file of host application:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFDuplexServiceTest.MessageService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="WCFDuplexServiceTest.IMessageService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFDuplexServiceTest/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!--Чтобы избежать раскрытия метаданных, 
          до развертывания задайте следующим параметрам значение "false".-->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- Чтобы получить сведения об исключениях в ошибках для отладки, 
          установите ниже значение TRUE. Перед развертыванием установите значение FALSE, 
           чтобы избежать разглашения сведений об исключении -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  
</configuration>
```

Config file of client application:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <wsDualHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IMessageService"
                     clientBaseAddress="http://localhost:8000/myClient/">
            <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
          </wsDualHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFDuplexServiceTest/Service1/"
                binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IMessageService"
                contract="MessageService.IMessageService" name="WSDualHttpBinding_IMessageService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

`IMessageService` implementation:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WCFDuplexServiceTest
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class MessageService : IMessageService
    {
        private List<IClientCallback> clientChannels = new List<IClientCallback>();
        private int numberOfUsers = 0;

    public MessageService() { }

    public void Register()
    {
        clientChannels.Add(OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IClientCallback>());
        numberOfUsers++;
    }

    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        foreach (var channel in clientChannels)
            channel.ShowMessage(message + string.Format("/nPeople online: {0}", numberOfUsers));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Post the code of implementation of  IMessageService and IMessageService contract.

Comment: Could you confirm that when client is running then you can acces your endpoint by other means than by the callback itself?

Comment: Client doesn't even receive data by calling simple operation which doesn't use a client's callback. It's still blocked.